# Scraping kenpom data in 2023

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have been scouring across the web to figure out how to use beautifulsoup and pandas to scrape kenpom.com college basketball data. I do not have an account to his website, hence why I am not using the kenpompy library. I have seen some past examples to scrape it from years past, including using the pracpred library (though I have zero experience on it, I'll admit) or using the curlconverter to grab the headers, cookies, and parameters during the requests.get, but now the website seems stingier in terms of grabbing the main table these days. I have used the following code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://kenpom.com/index.php?y=2023'

import requests

import requests

cookies = {
    'PHPSESSID': 'f04463ec42584dbd1bf7a480098947d1',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.120164513.1673124870',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.622021765.1673496414',
    '__stripe_mid': '71a4117b-cbef-4d3c-b31b-9d18e5c99a33183485',
    '__stripe_sid': '99b77b80-1222-4f7a-b2a8-acf5cf19c7d18a637f',
    'kenpomtry': 'https%3A%2F%2Fkenpom.com%2Fsummary.php%3Fs%3DRankAPL_Off%26y%3D2021',
    '_gat_gtag_UA_11558853_1': '1',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'kenpom.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    # 'cookie': 'PHPSESSID=f04463ec42584dbd1bf7a480098947d1; _ga=GA1.2.120164513.1673124870; _gid=GA1.2.622021765.1673496414; __stripe_mid=71a4117b-cbef-4d3c-b31b-9d18e5c99a33183485; __stripe_sid=99b77b80-1222-4f7a-b2a8-acf5cf19c7d18a637f; kenpomtry=https%3A%2F%2Fkenpom.com%2Fsummary.php%3Fs%3DRankAPL_Off%26y%3D2021; _gat_gtag_UA_11558853_1=1',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'y': '2023',
}

response = requests.get('https://kenpom.com/index.php', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

soup

# table = soup.find('table',{'id':'ratings-table'}).tbody
```

Any suggestions beyond this would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using requests and adding UserAgent as headers (It's pretty messy with multiple hierarchal indexes so will need further parsing to clean completely):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://kenpom.com/index.php?y=2023"

with requests.Session() as request:
    response = request.get(url, timeout=30,  headers=headers)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print(response.raise_for_status())

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

df = pd.concat(pd.read_html(str(soup)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. Unfortunately, I gave it a go with your code and still received a 403 forbidden error message on my end.